# PHP FTP uploader for large video files and directory creation

Tags: php, upload, ftp

So I need to have a site where people can submit videos for a school competition to an FTP (I have over a terabyte of disk space on my FTP server, hosted through lunarpages). Since this is a video uploader, it needs to be able to upload files at least 1GB. I've read numerous posts on this same topic, but with I could not find a solution to my problem through them. I have looked at various uploaders supported by flash, jquery. I tried to use this uploader https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload although it would not let me upload files more than 5 megabytes, even after I changed my upload_max_filesize to 10G and also my post_max_filesize, but it is still not letting me upload large files. Can someone point me in the direction of a fully functional free large ftp file uploader, or tell me what's wrong with the blueimp one? Thanks.

**EDIT**
my uploader example is live at http://www.dpreads.org/upload if anyone wants to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the demo notes ? `The maximum file size for uploads in this demo is 5 MB (default file size is unlimited).`

There is a max file size definition in the main.js, line 39.

`maxFileSize: 5000000`

This should solve your 5 meg problem but I doubt that will be enough for uploading a gig.